# reCaptcha Zend Framework Ajax

Tags: php, zend-framework, recaptcha

Hello having some issues with the recaptcha service in Zend framework , when loading some form that contains recaptcha dynamically (`trough .load()`)
any body knows how to pass the issue?

Comment: Can you give us any more detail on the issues?

Comment: Well the question was weather  Zend_recaptcha service ahs a support for recaptcha Ajax Api, but it seem that it doesn't. basically I about to implement recaptcha Ajax api in the recaptcha form element =)